# Setting TTL for collection using Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, ttl

Since MongoDB 2.2 it is possible to "[Expire Data from Collections Using a TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)" which is implemented as a special index type.

The latest version of Doctrine ORM supports this [Index Option](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/indexes.html#index-options). Unfortunately I have not been able to find how to correctly set this index using doctrine annotations/config files.

This is how I'm attempting to do it, I hope some one can help me setting it correctly:

```
<?php 

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="log")
 * @MongoDB\Indexes({
 *      @MongoDB\Index(keys={"expiration"=1, "expireAfterSeconds"=30})
 *      //... other indexes go here
 * })
 * 
 */
class Log
{
    // ...

    /** 
     * @MongoDB\Date 
     */
    protected $expiration;

    // ... 
}
```

Then when I execute `php app/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update` (in symfony 2.3.x)
The index is generated, but the index generated doesn't look correct.

this is what I get when I execute `db.system.indexes.find();` in my database:

```
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "expiration" : 1, "expireAfterSeconds" : 30 }, "ns" : "mydatabase.log", "sparse" : false, "name" : "expiration_1_expireAfterSeconds_-1" }
```

which is not the same as if I create the index manually:

```
db.log.ensureIndex( { "expiration": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30 } );
```

as it generates the following index:

```
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "expiration" : 1 }, "ns" : "mydatabase.log", "name" : "expiration_1", "expireAfterSeconds" : 30 }
```

How would I setup TTL on a date field using doctrine annotations/config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing index options with the `keys` parameter. The `Index` annotation also has an `options` parameter. See the example in the [Index annotation docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#index):

```
<?php

/**
 * @Document(
 *   indexes={
 *     @Index(keys={"username"="desc"}, options={"unique"=true})
 *   }
 * )
 */
class User
{
    //...
}
```

This is equivalent to passing `{unique: true}` as the second argument `db.collection.ensureIndex()`. You can replace `unique` with `expireAfterSeconds` to create a TTL index.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! what I ended up using based on your answer was:  @MongoDB\Index(keys={"expiration"=true}, options={"expireAfterSeconds"=30})